# Looping program based on user string input not gett

Tags: python

I need this program to do one of two things from my repeat function, but it should be able to do both and I can't work out why. 
It must do 2 things

- make it rerun my main() subprogram,
- or say "Goodbye." and close the entire program, 
  whichever one comes first.

I have tried making it just an if-else statement rather than if-elif-else, which didn't change anything, I have also tried rearranging the code, but that only changes the single output I can get from the subprogram. This is the subprogram currently:

```
def repeatloop():
  repeat = input("Do you want to calculate another bill? (y/n): ")
if repeat == 'n' or 'N':
  print("Goodbye.")
  time.sleep(2)
  sys.exit()
elif repeat == 'y' or 'Y':
  main()
else:
  print("Error. Program will shut down.")
  time.sleep(2)
  sys.exit()
```

It should be able to repeat the program (based on the y or Y input), terminate the program and display "Goodbye." based on the n or N input or it should display the "Error. Program will shut down." message before closing if an invalid input is entered.
Many thanks to whoever can help me!

Comment: Is your indentation correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value) Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/20002503

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `in ()` for the comparison with a list. It compares the value of the variable with the list.

```
def repeatloop():
  repeat = input("Do you want to calculate another bill? (y/n): ")
  if repeat in ('n','N'):
    print("Goodbye.")
    time.sleep(2)
    sys.exit()
  elif repeat in ('y','Y'):
    main()
  else:
    print("Error. Program will shut down.")
    time.sleep(2)
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow.
Your problem is that your `if` statements are not exactly correct; and also your whole function is not correctly indented.

`if repeat == 'n' or 'N'` is different from `if repeat == 'n' or repeat == 'N'`.

In the second  case, you test two different statements on the `repeat` keyword, where on the first one you're seeing whether:

1. `repeat` is equal to `n`, and also
2. `'N'` is not `None`; which isn't & this case always returns true.

Another way to do it could be `if repeat in ["n", "N"]` or even better: `if repeat.lower() == 'n'`

So put it all together, your code should be refined to:

```
def repeatloop():
    repeat = input("Do you want to calculate another bill? (y/n):")
    if repeat.lower() == 'n':
        print("Goodbye.")
        time.sleep(2)
        sys.exit()
    elif repeat.lower() == 'y':
        main()
    else:
        print("Error. Program will shuts down.")
        time.sleep(2)
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: `any(["n", "N"]) == repeat` won't give you the right answer either. You would be getting `True == repeat` which is always `False`.

Answer (score 0):

`if repeat == 'n' or 'N'` doesn't work, since you are checking `bool('N')` which is always true, the same holds true for `repeat == 'y' or 'Y'`, since
`bool('Y')` is always true.

You start by checking if repeat is in the list `['n','N']`, or is not in the list `['y','Y']`, then you exit the program, else you call the same function `repeatloop`

```
import time, sys

def repeatloop():
    repeat = input("Do you want to calculate another bill? (y/Y/n/N): ")
    if repeat in ['n', 'N']:
        print("Goodbye.")
        time.sleep(2)
        sys.exit()
    elif repeat in ['y', 'Y']:
       repeatloop()
    else:
        print("Error. Program will shut down.")
        time.sleep(2)
        sys.exit()

repeatloop()
```